# Laravel backend API and CRA React frontend(with react router) doesn't work -404 error

Tags: reactjs, laravel, production

I deployed demo version of application created with:

1. Laravel backend

   - based on breeze api
2. React.js frontend

   - CRA
   - react router

Aplication works properly in development. Frontend connect throw fetch action and loaders with backend. Application use CSRF token and default authentication.

Application was deployed in directory like this:

- root directory

  - index.html
  - static directory
  - (other react build directories and files)
  - backend folder

    - app
    - config
    - (other laravel files)

When I try to fetch data to laravel backend I got 404 page not found error. I checked url and they are set correctly (e.g. `https://example.com/backend/restOfDirectory`). When I try to reach `https://example.com/backend/public/index.php` it works properly and render `/` directory.

I tried to set 'backend' prefix on laravel routes, but it doesn't help.

I cannot find an answer why my backend refuse to work and if is it possible to configure laravel as backend api in root subdirectory.